# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded Nodejs mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, limit

Wanted to test the speed of inserting new documents in the database mongodb,
However, when the amount of insertion is very large, it returns the following error:
"RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"
Can anyone tell me why I get the message?

```
var counters2Schema = new mongoose.Schema({'_id': ObjectId, 'seq':String}, { versionKey: false, collection: 'counters'  }),

var k = 100000;
testCUPwrite function (i) {
     var MyObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
     MyObjectId = new MyObjectId();
     var counters2Model = new mongoose.model("counters", counters2Schema);
     new counters2Model({'seq': MyObjectId}). save ();
     console.log ('teste_' + MyObjectId);
     if (i <k) {
         i + +;
         setTimeout (testCUPwrite (i), 1);
     }

}
testCUPwrite (0);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
setTimeout (testCUPwrite (i), 1);
```

is not doing what you think it is. That's directly executing the `testCPUWrite` function in the current stack. It's not using `setTimeout` like you think. Something like

```
setTimeout(testCUPwrite.bind(null, i), 1);
```

Might get you going.